# How can I document config_accessor methods in YARD with TomDoc syntax?

Tags: ruby, yard, tomdoc

I'm working on code that includes ActiveSupport's Configurable module and I'm trying to document the config accessors.

Anybody know how to do so in YARD Tomdoc?

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to render anything in the docs.

```
class MyConf

  include ActiveSupport::Configurable

  # Is this configuration awesome? (defaults: true)
  config_accessor(:is_awesome) { true }

end
```

Answer (score 0):

This works!

```
class MyConf

  include ActiveSupport::Configurable

  ##
  # Is this configuration awesome? (defaults: true)
  config_accessor(:is_awesome) { true }

end
```